# Trouble reusing DownloadFile inside a BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, winforms, download

I have a simple class:

```
public class DownloadFile
{
    ...

    public string GetFile(string fileUrl, string pathOut)
    {
        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            wc.DownloadFile(new Uri(fileUrl), pathOut);
            return pathOut;
        }
    }
}
```

that I call it from a `BackgroundWorker` 2 times as the process is to download and install 2 files (Doing a custom Installer here).

Problem is that, the first file downloads and installs normally, but the 2nd file hangs on the `wc2.DownloadFile(new Uri(fileUrl), pathOut);` line and **never get's out from there**!

using `using` I'm disposing the `WebClient` every time I use, so I could say:

```
// Created BackgroundWorker so the UI doesn't get blocked and I can
//   can show the progress in a log...
BackgroundWorker bkWrk = new BackgroundWorker();
bkWrk.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
bkWrk.ProgressChanged += (s, e) =>
{
    ReportProgress(String.Format("Progress: {0}%", e.ProgressPercentage));
};
bkWrk.DoWork = delegate {

    DownloadFile fileManager = new DownloadFile();

    fileManager.GetFile("http://domain.com/file_A.zip", "C:\\TEMP\\file_a.zip");
    fileManager.GetFile("http://domain.com/file_B.zip", "C:\\TEMP\\file_b.zip");
};
bkWrk.RunWorkerAsync();

while(bkWrk.IsBusy)
{
    // let's wait but fire all events 
    Application.DoEvents();
}
```

I do not see any problem here ... but the truth is that the file hangs on the `DownloadFile` method, even tried using the Microsoft Symbols to navigate inside the method with no luck.

Even added a header to the request, but still, the problem remains

```
wc.Headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/4.0 (Compatible; Windows NT 5.1; MSIE 6.0)" +
                           " (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)";
```

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Does the second file exist? I know it's an obvious question - but you have to ask!

Comment: it does ... bigger problem, is that sometimes it download both files without a problem :-/

Comment: Try to make GetFile method Static

Comment: There's no documented failure mode like this for WebClient.  Does it work okay on the main thread?  Have you eliminated the server as the problem?

Answer (score 0):

> DownloadFile fileManager = new DownloadFile(); 
>   fileManager.GetFile("http://domain.com/file_A.zip",
>   "C:\TEMP\file_a.zip");
>   fileManager.GetFile("http://domain.com/file_B.zip",
>   "C:\TEMP\file_b.zip");

You do understand that wc.DownloadFile isn't an Async method right?  This means your background worker must download the first file, then the second file, before its work has been completed.

> it does ... bigger problem, is that sometimes it download both files
>   without a problem :-/ –

This just means you waited long enough for both actions to be completed.

Comment: inside the `BackgroundWorker` I have the explicit code I wrote that calls the 2 methods, because the call happens inside the `BackgroundWorker` the second `GetFile()` will always fire only when the first is concluded. - I added the bkWrk code that wraps the `GetFile`'s

Comment: The BackgroudnWorker will download the two files one after another within an Async operating.  DownloadFile is NOT an Async operating.  What you want to use is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.net.webclient.downloadfileasync(v=VS.100).aspx this is a better method ovrall

Comment: I do NOT want to use `DownloadFileAsync`, that will invoke a thread on each file, I already have one from the `BackgroundWorker` there is no need to keep creating threads if I want things to happen in a sync mode inside the `BackgroundWorker`.

Comment: You're right that there is no need to use async if you want to do things synchronously (it's simpler). But async methods don't create new threads, they use [IO completion ports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365198.aspx).