# Timeout is firing but app continues normally

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, download

I have been having a small problem that I can't by-pass it, I keep trying to change the way I get the file, but I end up having the same problem

[original image below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrSw4.png)

[image]

My idea is that I have an `.xml` file that I download and that has a list of files to download and install.

I get the `.xml` file fine, extract it and start download files... the 1st goes very well, the 2nd sometimes get timeout ... **problem is**... after the timeout error, it does continue and install that *hanged* file, but it will freeze the entire app while hanging into timeout exception.

the code idea is that I need to know where are we in downloading the file, so I used this [idea](http://devtoolshed.com/content/c-download-file-progress-bar).

I also found out that `WebClient` and `WebRequest` have a [strange timeout issue](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/478102/webclient-and-webrequest-have-strange-timeouts) when dealt in a  multithread environment.

> What's the best pattern to, in a window form, download files (several files) and output the percentage while downloading?

So I can do something about this, and I'm getting out of ideas ...

[My latest question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7673820/trouble-reusing-downloadfile-inside-a-backgroundworker) was also related to this issue.

Comment: Is there a reason why you do not create a WebClient instance in the DoWork delegate (as in the linked example)?

Comment: The progress bar idea seems good. Have you tried it?

Comment: @Tudor (???) The idea is implemented in the code that you see in the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using something like [this open source C# downloader tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/MyDownloader.aspx).  It provides segmented downloading of files over http and ftp (with several other options).  It provides feedback and it's all wrapped in a developer friendly API.

Comment: seams like a very nice project ... I ended up removing some `BackgroundWorker`'s and everything started to work ... I guess that .NET does not like to much threads...